# How to create nth level tree hierarchy structure in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a Product XML with parent,childs,grandchilds....upto nth level. I want to parse this xml & create a tree structure out of it & display in vf page. I saw an example of accounts,contacts & cases using subquery but in that the level of hierarchy was fixed(upto 3 levels).

Answer (score 5):

Without resorting to client-side rendering, you can do it like this.

First, create a Node class to store nodes and their children.

```
public class Node {
    public String title { get; set; }
    public Node[] children { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a node Visualforce Component that renders itself and its children:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="node" type="Node" required="true" description="The current node to render" />
    <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <div>{!node.title}</div>
        <apex:repeat value="{!node.children}" var="child">
            <c:node node="{!child}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

In your page, start by populating a root node, then recursively go down through its children. You can also add attributes, etc, to make it as complex as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks.. also just wanted to know will it work for multiple hierarchy? ex:- A is the root element & it has 3 childs B,C & D which in turn has subchilds,grandchilds....nth level. Also can you let me know how is the child hierarchy maintained in Node[] array, is it related to the position of elements in array? ex:- [P,Q,R] Q is child of P & R is the child of Q like that?